# Sitecore GlassMapper with Helix

Tags: glass-mapper

We need to make choice between Sitecore Extensions and Glass Mapper along with T4 to get the Data for Sitecore Items for our project. Can you guys help me challenges you face using Glass Mapper when you use GlassMapper for first time

I know its generic questions but it would be great if you could help me with challenges you face using Glassmapper,Habitat and T4.

Answer (score 0):

We recently implemented Glass Mapper withe Helix. Crated a ORM project in foundation having all Glass configs and startup classes there which is referenced all other prjs (both Foundation and Feature).

Things to consider-
1. Create a DI prj in foundation and refer it in Glass prj for class you may want to register e.g.:- ISitecoreContext, IRenderingContext etc.
2. Although Glass prj is referred in all other prj's you may have to install Glass itself in all prjs removing configs and statup.cs(s) file just to have reference which is a tedious job.(May be there is a good way of doing this, but we have implemented this way)
3. Over the time there may be new versions of Glass mapper which may conflict with previous prj's
TIP:- you may consider to create a powershell script for adding a new module from Package manager itself. Please look at this link - http://blog.marcduiker.nl/2016/12/28/hands-on-with-sitecore-helix-using-powershell-add-module.html

Hope this helps.